# Java String pool and type casting

Tags: java, string, compiler-construction, jvm

My question is in regard to the way Java handles String literals. It's quite clear from the Java Language Specs (JLS) that String literals are being implicitly interned - in other words, objects that are created in the String constant pool part of the heap, in contrast to the heap-based objects created when calling `new String("whatever")`.

What doesn't seem to line up with what the JLS says is that when creating a new String using String concatenation with a casted constant String type, which should be considered as a constant String as per the JLS, apparently the JVM is creating a new String object rather than interning it implicitly. I appreciate any explanation about this particular behaviour and whether or not this is a platform-specific behaviour. I am running on a Mac OSX Snow Leopard.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        /*
            Create a String object on the String constant pool
            using a String literal
        */
        String hello = "hello";
        final String lo = "lo"; // this will be created in the String pool as well
        /*
            Compare the hello variable to a String constant expression
            , that should cause the JVM to implicitly call String.intern()
        */
        System.out.println(hello == ("hel" + lo));// This should print true
        /*
            Here we need to create a String by casting an Object back
            into a String, this will be used later to create a constant
            expression to be compared with the hello variable
        */
        Object object = "lo";
        final String stringObject = (String) object;// as per the JLS, casted String types can be used to form constant expressions
        /*
            Compare with the hello variable
        */
        System.out.println(hello == "hel" + stringObject);// This should print true, but it doesn't :(

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use == for strings, use String1.equals(string2)

Comment: @dann.dev: I think you've missed the point of the question.

Comment: The whole thing is about where objects are created, not what objects are created.

Comment: Won't it have an effect on the comparison operation though?

Comment: Could you link to the part of the JLS that says expressions casted to `String` will be put into the constant pool? My hunch is the second expression simply cannot be constant-folded, because the compiler doesn't do the dataflow analysis required to figure out that `stringObject` is the constant `"lo"`.

Comment: Nope, it won't. == is used to compare of two String reference variables are referring to the exact same object, i.e. the exact same memory address if you like.

Comment: @dann.dev The OP's not asking how to compare strings, he's asking how constant string expressions work in Java.

Comment: Sorry, knew that wasn't about comparing but thought it might affect it anyway, have run it and get what you mean now

Comment: this link may prove insightful: http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/lang/strLiteral.html

Comment: @Hasanein - I edited to try and clarify the question. Please feel free to re-edit if you feel I distorted anything.

Comment: Cheers Paul, looks much now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting to `Object` is not allowed in a compile time constant expression. The only casts permitted are to `String` and primitives. JLS (Java SE 7 edition) section 15.28:

[> - Casts to primitive types and casts to type String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

(There's actually a second reason. `object` isn't `final` so cannot possibly by considered a [constant variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4). "A variable of primitive type or type `String`, that is `final` and initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is called a constant variable." -- section 4.12.4.)

Comment: I am casting an Object into a String, so that should form a constant expression, no?

Comment: The implicit cast to Object means that it is no longer constant.

Comment: @Hasanein, that's not the issue -- it's that the `Object` variable that is assigned to a string that is not a constant.

Comment: Changing object to be final still produces a similar result. Can you give an example of forming a constant string expression using casting to Strings ?

Comment: @Hasanein `"hi" == "h"+(String)"i"`

Comment: Thanks, but casting is not necessary here as you are casting a String literal into an object of String which does have the very same effect if you omit the casting. I am more concerned with having Strings hidden in object instances that need to be casted back to String objects

Comment: @Hasanein I can't see how that can happen inside a compile time constant expression.

Comment: @TomHawtin thanks a lot, clear now that the only use case for String casting is casting a String literal (or constant object) back to String, any other attempt to cast any other object to String is a runtime operation which invalidates the conditions for a constant expression

Answer (score 3):

Seems like because you reference an object here `final String stringObject = (String) object;`, this is no longer a 'compile-time' constant, but a 'run-time' constant. The first example from [here](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3) eludes to it with the part:

```
String s = "lo";
String str7 = "Hel"+ s;  
String str8 = "He" + "llo"; 
System.out.println("str7 is computed at runtime.");     
System.out.println("str8 is created by using string constant expression.");    
System.out.println("    str7 == str8 is " + (str7 == str8));  
System.out.println("    str7.equals(str8) is " + str7.equals(str8));
```

The string str7 is computed at runtime, because it references another string that is not a literal, so by that logic I assume despite that face that you make `stringObject` final, it still references an object, so cannot be computed at compile time.

And from the java lang spec [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.3), it states:

"The string concatenation operator + (§15.18.1) implicitly creates a new String object when the result is not a compile-time constant expression (§15.28). "

I cannot find any examples where a cast can be used, except, for this terrible, terrible example:

```
System.out.println(hello == "hel" + ( String ) "lo");
```

Which hardly has any logical use, but maybe the part about a string cast was included because of the above case.

Comment: Thanks dann, You are right, I think that the only reason thats mentioned in the specs is to support casting a String back to String which I can't see much practical use to it either.