# Java String literals concatenation

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        one();
        two();
        three();
    }

    public static void one() {
        String s1 = "hill5";
        String s2 = "hill" + 5;
        System.out.println(s1==s2);
    }

    public static void two() {
        String s1 = "hill5";
        int i =5;
        String s2 = "hill" + i;
        System.out.println(s1==s2);
    }

    public static void three() {
        String s1 = "hill5";
        String s2 = "hill" + s1.length();
        System.out.println(s1==s2);
    }
```

Output is

```
true 
false 
false
```

String literals use interning process,then why `two()` and `three()` is false.I can understand in case of `three()` but `two()` is not clear.but need proper explanation for both cases.

Can someone please explain proper reason?

Comment: read this question which i asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729045/behavior-of-string-literals-are-confusing

Comment: For fun, you can also try `two` with `final int i = 5;` instead (it will print true instead of false, because now `i` is a constant).

Comment: "every time someone compares Strings with == a developer cries..."

Comment: Note that you should not ever rely on `==` to compare strings - it will make your program brittle.  This is simply a question of when strings are interned and that depends on the compiler used (in `one()`) and the JVM used.

Comment: yup,I want to know concept only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In case of 2 and 3 , Compiler cannot calculate the value of String , since `hill + i` is a runtime statement , same for `s1.length()`

read here which i asked the same case - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729045/behavior-of-string-literals-are-confusing)

Think like this the `String s1 and s2` are using compile time constant , `s1="hill5"` and `s2="hill" + 5` , remember , string assigned as a literal is constant , its state cannot be modified , as **String are immutable**.

So at Compile time , compiler says "oh yeah , they are calculated as same value , i must assign the same reference to s1 and s2".

But in case of method `two()` and `three()` , compiler says " i dont know ,may be value of i can be changed any time , or `s1.length()`  changes any time " , its a runtime thing , so  compiler doesn't put s2 of `two()` and `three()` method in pool ,

Hence , they are false because at runtime , new object is created as soon it get changed right !!

Comment: But String literals are created as part of heap and jvm check whether String exists or not,if not  then it creates new String otherwise points to same location..so in case of two and three hill5 String is there in pool

Comment: @ankitagahoi Not really - only constant strings are put in the pool, unless you use the `intern` method...

Comment: all literals not goes to pool?

Comment: @ankitagahoi `"hill" + i` is not a String literal. `"hill5"` is... See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5

Comment: so in case of two and three jvm will not check Strings in pool, it will create a new String ,am i right?

Comment: @ankitagahoi JVM will check that string s2 of two() and three() method is referring to new object so it will check reference that it does not refer to pool literal "hill5"

Comment: hey before you go read this too , for scjp and correct clearance http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/ScjpTipLine-StringsLiterally.html

Comment: @anshulkatta The JVM doesn't check any such thing. The compiler puts string literals in the constant pool: the OP's code creates new strings. You're just making it up, even after the same statement has already been corrected. Twice. The normative reference is the JLS and the JVM specification, not another forum.

Answer (score 1):

String with compile time constant expression will be put on String pool. The main condition is compile time constant expression. If you make local variable final in method `two()` then `two()` will also print `true`

```
public static void two() {
    String s1 = "hill5";
    final int i =5;
    String s2 = "hill" + i;
    System.out.println(s1==s2);
}
```

Output:

```
true
```