# object1.toString() == object2.toString()

Tags: java, object, reference, tostring, assignment-operator

The below is my main method in which am comparing two object references. Having overridden the `toString()` method in Car class, my question is why are the below "if" conditions evaluating to false when they should evaluate to true. Could somebody explain? Thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        Car c1 = new Car(2829,"white");
        Car c2 = new Car(2829,"white");

        if(c1 == c2)
            System.out.println(true);
        else
            System.out.println(false);

        String sc1 = c1.toString();
        String sc2 = c2.toString();

        if(sc1 == sc2)
            System.out.println("it's equal");
        else
            System.out.println("it's not!");
    }


public class Car {
    private int regNo;
    private String color;

    protected void start(){
        System.out.println("Car Started!");
    }

    public Car(int regNo, String color){
        this.regNo = regNo;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car-"+regNo;
    }
}
```

Say, i have two strings `s1="abc" and s2 = "abc"`. Now, `s1 == s2` evaluating to true then why is that in the above code `c1.toString() == c2.toString()` evaluating to false is my question?

Comment: Because use `equals`.

Comment: The second part of this question is a dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729045/behavior-of-string-literals-are-confusing

Answer (score 1):

Well, because `==` compares references and

1. The reference c1 is not *same as* c2
2. `c1.toString().equals(c2.toString())` is the right way to compare Strings.

Comment: Well, i know equals() is the right way to compare, however when the below is evaluating to true why isn't the above?  String s1 = "abc"; String s2="abc"; s1==s2 - evaluates to true

Comment: Strings are immutable objects any modification create a new instance (like your toString() methods).

Comment: @Jsm - by default, at *object* level both `==` and `equals()` compare references. So, they will return `false` c1 is not c2. You will have to *override* `equals()` and then change its *default* mplementation and then use `c1.equals(c2)`. For Strings, `equals()` has already been implemented (overidden), So, `.equals()` compares *contents* of 2 *different* string instances.

Comment: >  String s1 = "abc"; String s2="abc"; s1==s2 

Because "" does not create a new string, instead it uses string pooling.