# How is memory alocated with Strings in Java?

Tags: java, string, memory, string-pool

Having the following code:

```
String s="JAVA";
for(i=0; i<=100; i++)
     s=s+"JVM";
```

How many Strings are created? My guess is that 103 Strings are created:

1: the String "JAVA" in the String pool

1: the String "JVM" also in the String pool

101: the new String `s` is created every time in the loop because the String is an Immutable class

Comment: jit may try replacing it with an arraylist of chars until s is referenced for used

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik - 1) AFAIK, it won't ... in an release of Java so far.  2) According to a strict reading of JLS 15.18.1, the JIT compiler is not permitted to do that.

Answer (score 3):

String concatenation is implemented through the `StringBuilder`(or `StringBuffer`) class and its `append` method. String conversions are implemented through the method `toString`, defined by `Object` and inherited by all classes in Java. For additional information on string concatenation and conversion, see *Gosling, Joy, and Steele, The Java Language Specification.*

In your case, 103 strings are created, one for each in the loop and the two Strings `Java` and `JVM`.

Comment: The JLS states that string concatenation *may be* implemented using StringBuilder.  It does not state that it is required to be implemented that way.

Answer (score 1):

When using '+' operator on string, JAVA replace it by a StringBuilder each time.

So for each loop you create a `StringBuilder` that concat the two strings (s and JVM) with the method `append()` then its converted to a String by the `toString()` method

Answer (score 1):

Compile-time string expressions are  put into the String pool.
s=s+"JVM" is not a compile-time constant expression. so everytime it creates a new string object in heap.

for more details see this [Behavior of String literals is confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729045/behavior-of-string-literals-is-confusing)